# WebSocket guaranteed delivery free framework

Tags: websocket, qos, java-websocket

I have some kind of system that send messages from Java back-end to Web front-end constantly. I use Openfire with XMPP protocol as a transport system. But XMPP is just a transport protocol, it do not guaranty delivery in case when Internet connection is down. So firstly I decided to switch to more light transport protocol - WebSocket. And again WebSocket is just a transport protocol. Is there any production ready and free message delivery framework based on WebSockets that support message guaranteed delivery. You just send message with clientId and that framework will do the rest. If user is offline or Internet connection is down. I mean that framework will care about delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I would shift responsibility of assuring message delivery away from your transport choice and onto some message queueing system like rabbitMQ or similar - here is a blip from their feature set :

**"Queues can be mirrored across several machines in a cluster, ensuring that even in the event of hardware failure your messages are safe"**